# How to use logical and in c++

Tags: c++

```
if (age > 40 && age < 60)
```

or

```
if (age > 40  & age < 60)
```

As you can see I am not sure if C++ uses two and signs or one.

Comment: Any C++ textbook or other reference should explain this. `&&` is logical "and"; `&` is bitwise "and".

Comment: I would suggest you to go through http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: C++ also provides `and` as an alternate way of spelling `&&`.  ([Really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h#C.2B.2B).)

Answer (score 7):

The first one is the correct Logical AND `if (age > 40 && age < 60)`

- `&&` is a [Logical AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) operator
- `&` - could be a [Reference ("address of") operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Member_and_pointer_operators) or a [`Bitwise AND`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator (which is the case in your second example) depending on where it appears in expression. Also, see [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++).

Comment: In this case, `&` is the bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the correct results:

```
if ((age > 40) && (age < 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's &&, single ampersand is a bitwise and function. In a lot of cases it may work out the same if you are using ints, but there will be other data types that cause problems.

Comment: Even with ints it might cause problems, because the two operators have different precedence. Also & always evaluates both operands while && doesn't evaluate the rhs if the lhs is false.